# How to disable arrays in query string in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

How do I make express.js query parser only populate req.query with strings?

Example code:

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
app.set('query parser', 'simple');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.query);
});

app.listen(1337);
```

When I call `curl "localhost:1337/?a=1&a=2"`, I get `{"a":["1","2"]}`, I want to get `{"a":"2"}` or `{"a":"1"}`. Is there any way to do this without making custom middleware?

Thanks

Comment: Check if `req.query.a` is a string and if not response with a 400

Comment: @pzaenger cool, so if I have 1000 routes I just repeat this process 1000 times?

Comment: `const a = Array.isArray(request.query.a) ? request.query.a[0] : request.query.a`, or use a middleware to do it for every possible entry of the query.

Comment: @eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee Then use a custom middleware - though you wrote _Is there any way to do this without making custom middleware?_

Comment: You will need to manually handle this querystring case, as express has no opinion here. This is how express handles multi-value querystring entries. You also may want to let some querystring values be arrays in the future. You could use middlware with an allowlist/denylist of array parameters, a function, or logic in each callback function. In general, you're _parsing_ input data, and you have to validate it no matter what. Tools like zod are common for parsing + validating raw user input data. Route specific input parsing is a common need in webapps.